# Why does IIS 7 return a 500 when I access an HTML page?

Tags: iis-7, html

IIS 7 returns a 500 server error when I request an HTML page with this structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Some text
</body> 
</html>
```

It works just fine the first time I access it, but subsequent attempts cause the error.

If I remove the HTML tags, the error doesn't occur:

```
<body>
Some text 
</body>
```

It seems very odd that the presence of the HTML tag would cause it to blow up.

The HTML doesn't blow up if I rename the file to .aspx.

Any ideas?

Comment: Timely question.  Just ran into the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I would check the Application Pool, we have had an issue before at my company where code was causing an error and the App pool would just shut down, nothing short of restarting the box/changing code would make things any better.

Answer (score 0):

The event log (either Application or System) should contain details about any errors that are occurring in IIS.